Inconsistent Output with HuggingFace ChatHuggingFace in Google Colab and Langchain Documentation
I am using the HuggingFace ChatHuggingFace module to generate text in a Google Colab notebook. However, I noticed that the output I receive differs from the output shown in the Langchain documentation, even when using the same code and input messages.
My output: 
<|system|>
You're a helpful assistant</s>
<|user|>
What happens when an unstoppable force meets an immovable object?</s>
<|assistant|>
According to the popular idiom, when an unstoppable force meets an immovable object, there is a       paradoxical situation where both...... in the real world.

Output of https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/chat/huggingface/#instantiate-the-chathuggingface-to-apply-chat-templates:
According to the popular idiom, when an unstoppable force meets an immovable object, there is a paradoxical situation where both...... in the real world.
I'm expecting the output to be similar to the second output.

Did you solve this issue? I am too facing this issue.

This is probably due to the temperature of your LLM.
The temperature is the deterministic property of your model, higher temperature = more different answers to same question and lower means more deterministic answers.

Temperature is default yet getting this output
